# Running Angular Application: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I found this error when I tried to run an angular application. Any tip?

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
at module.exports 



Error: Cannot find module '/home/isaac-wahba/Development/Personal/Udacity/Deployment/deployment-process-project/udagram/udagram-frontend/–openssl-legacy-provider'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v17.4.0
```

Note: I tried the following:

- Changing the Webpack version to 4.39.2
- Changing it to 5.61.0.

- The result was

> ```
>  An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/ParserHelpers'
> ```

Comment: if you try to run int locally i would use angular cli and the run either npm start or ng serve depending how the configs are set up.

Comment: here's a long discussion of the issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve it by changing:

1. `node` version to 16.
2. `webpack` version to 4.

Comment: tried a lot of things, this was the only one that worked

Comment: I ended up installing nvm for Windows so that I could try various versions of Node to correct this issue.  Highly recommend!  Here's the link: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#node-version-manager-nvm-for-windows

Answer (score 36):

Windows:
`set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

Mac/Linux:
`export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

Add the `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider &&`  in your scripts start command.

For example your previous script like:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve"
}
```

Then after you have

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng serve"
}
```

Then run `npm start`

Comment: For those of us using Powershell instead of the command prompt on Windows, type `$env:NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"` instead.

Comment: the command `"start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng serve"`works for me!