# dockerizing Angular project, error NG8001, NG8002, NG8003

Tags: angular, docker

I've noticed several errors during dockerizing Angular project while there is no error when I'm running either `ng serve` or `npm run build` commands. having said that  I set `"strict": false,` in tsconfig.json file.

I used this command to the dockerize angular project:

```
docker build -t myProject:latest .
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
#stage 1
FROM node:16.15.0 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/myProject /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I can say there is an error for every single component and module in my project, for example:

```
error NG8001: 'mat-paginator' is not a known element:
error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors
error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'pageSizeOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'.
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'length' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'.
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'label' since it isn't a known property of 'app-text-input'.
```

Here is the lastest out put before the error comes up:

[image]

All Versioning:

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.7
Node: 16.15.0
Package Manager: npm 8.5.5
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.3.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.7
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.7
@angular/cdk                    13.3.7
@angular/cli                    13.3.7
@angular/material               13.3.7
@schematics/angular             13.3.7
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.6.4
```

UPDATE:

I've put `.dockerignore` in the root of the project in the same directory as `node_modules`.

**.dockerignore:**

```
node_modules
.angular
```

Comment: This looks like `node_modules` is not generated properly, or you copy folder hierarchy before it is generated, also what is that space between `/` and `app` for? and the `.` must be separated from `COPY`

Comment: @tony Actually there was some typo in the text I copied in here, but everything was correct in my Dockerfile, I just edit the post.

Comment: You mention there is no error when running `ng serve`, I suppose there is also no error when running `npm run build` outside the container?

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore`? If yes, can you add its content?

Comment: @JSONDerulo There are a few errors with `npm run build` that totally different from what was I mentioned in the question. No, I don't have `.dockerignore`

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: It‘s not recommended to use different major versions of Angular packages, have you tried updating `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/Material` to v13? Also Angular CLI does caching since v13, maybe you can try to disable the cache or add the `.angular` directory to the `.dockerignore`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245120/discussion-between-distance-and-json-derulo).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Don't share the `node_modules` between host and container

It looks like your `node_modules` cause troubles. Docker runs in Linux containers, while your machine may have another OS. However, some packages contain compiled code for a specific OS, i.e. `node-sass`, which cannot be shared between different OS. In your current setup, the `node_modules` of your host are copied into the container.

To work around this issue, add a [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file to the directory where your `DOCKERFILE` lives, with the following content:

```
node_modules
```

This will stop copying the `node_modules` from the host into the container. Also I would recommended to use `npm ci` instead of `npm install`.

Comment: I add `.dockerignore` in the node_modules  folder but I got the same error. I tried with adding `.dockerignore` in the root of the project and add `**/node_modules` in it. but the same error happened.

Comment: having said that I fixed errors that came with `npm run build`

Comment: I just update the question and add the picture of last output result before the error.

Comment: @distance You need to put it in the same directory as the `DOCKERFILE`, forgot that to mention

Comment: Yes, I did. I put it in the same directory as `DOCKERFILE`